# Configuring maven to check integrity checksums when downloading artifacts from repository and/or building a project?

Tags: java, maven, checksum, data-integrity

In some situations (like not having money on balance), my internet provider redirects any HTTP request to a simple html stub.
Recently maven cache on my dev machive was flooded by jar files with content consisting of an html stub from my internet provider. These jar files were not noticed during the build and ended up being deployed to Tomcat as a part of my project artifacts. I noticed problem thanks to warnings about corrupted jar files at Tomcat log. Obviously, I want to avoid this situation in future.

I see that at a maven cache, there are `*.sha1` files that are expected to contain integrity checksums for jar files. In my case, these `*.sha1` had also wrong content (consisting of an html stub).

How can I configure maven to fail during artifact download or during build process if jar file content does not match the integrity checksum?

The Maven version I use is `3.3.9`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pass the command-line option `--strict-checksums`.

https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html#running-sect-deps-option

> -C, --strict-checksums
>
> Fail the build if checksums don’t match

Comment: Thanks. Expected that to work by default and googling did not point to this flag

Comment: @Dmitriusan Nope, the default seems to be that you get a warning.

Comment: Yes, and the warning is not noticeable when building a relatively huge enterprise project. Thank you for pointing me to this flag, I've also set up Maven to fail during build at IntelliJ IDEA global maven settings

Comment: Please go vote for this to be enabled by default: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5728

Answer (score 0):

In Maven `4.0.0-alpha-2`, if a downloaded file fails the checksum check, the build will fail. This used to be a warning.

Jira-Issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5728

Answer (score 0):

If you work with an IDE like IntelliJ, there is an option as well:

[image]